# Does elasticsearch ignore dot in match_phrase?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using `match_phrase` to do a search like:

```
"match_phrase": {
                            "name": "XX .S"
                          }
```

And it finds the result which has name as `"name" : "XX S&#",` and `"name": "XX S Ltd"`. It seems that it ignores `.` in the search. After some investigation, the `dot` may be striped during indexing when it tokenise the words inside the string. If this is true, how can I make the search treat `dot` as a regular character?
If it is not true, what causes that and how can I fix it?

What I am expecting is that I can get below response by querying `XX .S`

```
A XX .S B
XX .S
XX .S11
XX .Sa
```

The only issue about `match_phrase` I found so far is that it doesn't escape `.`. It works perfect for other cases.

Comment: Use wildcard query just like my answer. Can not paste the query by comments, will be filtered by website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define "name" as keyword type while you are creating the index. Default is text type which will be tokenized by Elastic Search engine.

```
name": {
    "type": "keyword"
}
```

Use wild card:

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 200,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "wildcard": {
                                    "name": {
                                        "wildcard": "*XX .S*",
                                        "boost": 1
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "adjust_pure_negative": true,
                        "boost": 1
                    }
                }
            ],
            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
            "boost": 1
        }
    },
    "_source": {
        "includes": [
            "name"
        ],
        "excludes": []
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I change it to be `keyword`, I can't search `XX .SA`, `B XX .S A` by querying `XX .S`. What I need is to make the `.` as regular character.

Comment: TRY THIS QUERY:


{
 "from": 0,
 "size": 200,
 "query": {
  "bool": {
   "filter": [
    {
     "bool": {
      "must": [
       {
        "wildcard": {
         "name": {
          "wildcard": "*Level1 .*",
          "boost": 1
         }
        }
       }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1
     }
    }
   ],
   "adjust_pure_negative": true,
   "boost": 1
  }
 },
 "_source": {
  "includes": [
   "name"
  ],
  "excludes": []
 }
}

Comment: I change the answer.

Comment: Why do you use nested `bool` query? What is the impact if I remove the top two keys `bool` and `filter`?

Comment: it is also ok.  nested is because if there is other conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the old search logic by introducing/(***not replacing***) a more `keyword` field like this.

```
{
  "foo": {
    "type" "text",
    "fields": {
      "raw": { 
        "type":  "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And you can perform full-text search with `foo.raw` field.

This is what you need to query to have results

```
{
    "query": {
        "wildcard": {
            "foo.raw": "*XX .S*"
        }
    }
}
```

See more details at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/multi-fields.html

Best,

Comment: If I do that, a search `.XXX` will response some results which doesn't contain `.`. Because it matches the old search logic. I'd like to response an empty result if there is no name contains `.XXX`.

Comment: You should only search on field `foo.raw` and it matches only the `.XXX` value. You probably remove the old logic out of your implementation on `foo`. This enables since the field with `type=keyword` would not be tokenized by ES

Comment: By using `type=keyword`, it won't support partial query on the field. I added a few examples on my post which are not supported by keyword query.

Comment: Please see the updated query using `wildcard` matching on `foo.raw`