# why elasticsearch can not search a document contains one word?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using default settings for one index, follow DSL is how to create the documents and searching.

```
### create index 
PUT /mk_test 
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "number_of_replicas": 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "nickName": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


### get index
GET /mk_test/_mapping

### create document
POST /mk_test/_doc
{
  "nickName": "C.BP"
}
### create document
POST /mk_test/_doc
{
  "nickName": "BP"
}
### create document
POST /mk_test/_doc
{
  "nickName": "C.B"
}

### create document
POST /mk_test/_doc
{
  "nickName": "你好，中国"
}
```

now I have 4 document in `mk_test` index,
and I have 2 search query, give me different answers.

1. I want to query docs contains "中国"

```
GET /mk_test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"match_phrase": {"nickName": "中国"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

server responses:

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.5779729,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "mk_test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "c2gwwX0BTkUG9klh1b8k",
        "_score" : 1.5779729,
        "_source" : {
          "nickName" : "你好，中国"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

2. I want to query docs contains "BP", I can't get "C.BP",

```
GET /mk_test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"match_phrase": {"nickName": "BP"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

server give me only "BP", but "C.BP" not found

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.4599355,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "mk_test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "TmguwX0BTkUG9klhAJ_S",
        "_score" : 1.4599355,
        "_source" : {
          "nickName" : "BP"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How can I find both "BP" and "C.BP" ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does elasticsearch ignore dot in match\_phrase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59779701/does-elasticsearch-ignore-dot-in-match-phrase)

Comment: That answer probably works but using leading wildcard is usually not recommended depending on the data volume and hardware on which the query is run.

Comment: Yes, I think this answer will cause great performance loss